How to select specific element with multiple elements but without class or id
I am trying to do this without anything but pure css, I am trying to select a specific fieldset without touching the other fieldsets as there are a lot of other fieldsets with legends and submit buttons in the website
html (cannot edit)
<fieldset></fieldset>
<fieldset></fieldset>
<fieldset></fieldset>
<fieldset></fieldset>
<fieldset></fieldset>
...
<fieldset>
<p> Normal background below is the fieldset to change background for</p>
<fieldset>
<legend></legend>
<p class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Edit" name="commit">
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="commit">
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="commit">
</p>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>


css
\\fieldset with submit button no class no id\\
{
background: black;
}


fieldset:has(.submit), fieldset:not(:empty),  etc etc. Read about CSS selectors you'll immediately find the one that best fits your specific task. Also, there are already many questions here on Stack Overflow covering that problem — do a research.

there are many fieldsets with submit buttons inside it but for some reason this particular html remains the default colors, I'd like to select everything in that fieldset, the   input types making the selection very specific

Okay I finally managed to find a way to select everything, I didn't realise that there was a fieldset above the fieldset I wanted to select so it became a whole hot mess lol
css
fieldset > fieldset:has(+legend,
p.submit,
input[value|="edit"],
input[value|="save"],
input[value|="delete"]){
background: black;
}

